# The ASP.NET ETW provider on a win7 PC is missing

Tags: asp.net, trace, provider, etw

I am writing an ETW consumer to listen for ASP.NET events. I have the sample code below working nicely on a Windows 2008 server where it can see the ASP.NET provider.  The problem that I am running into is that on my Win7 (64) PC, I do not see the ASP.NET provider so this code shows all the events as “unhandled”.
I have made sure the tracing feature is installed and the applicationhost.config file has the respective values in it.

When I do a logman –query providers, I do not see the 
ASP.NET AFF081FE-0247-4275-9C4E-021F3DC1DA35 provider on the PC, but I see this on the Win2008 server that I am testing on.

How can I do one of the two items below:
Add this as a provider to my Win7 PC?

OR

Have the code able to handle this message and provide the manifest in my code.  When I set “AFF081FE-0247-4275-9C4E-021F3DC1DA35” as a provider, I do get events but they are from unknown provider.  So I am guessing the manifest content is missing.

My sample code is below

```
    static void Test3()
    {
        var sessionName = "ASPNETMonitorSession";
        using (var session = new TraceEventSession(sessionName, null))  
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting Test1");
            session.StopOnDispose = true;
            Console.CancelKeyPress += delegate(object sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs e)
            {
                session.Dispose();
            };
            using (var source = new ETWTraceEventSource(sessionName, TraceEventSourceType.Session))
            {
                Action<TraceEvent> action = delegate(TraceEvent data)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("GOT EVENT: " + data.ToString());
                };

                var registeredParser = new RegisteredTraceEventParser(source);
                registeredParser.All += action;
                source.UnhandledEvents += delegate(TraceEvent data)
                {
                    if ((int)data.ID != 0xFFFE)         
                        Console.WriteLine("GOT UNHANDLED EVENT: " + data.Dump());
                };

                session.EnableProvider(new Guid("AFF081FE-0247-4275-9C4E-021F3DC1DA35"));
                Console.WriteLine("Starting Listening for events");
                source.Process();                                                              
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why ASP.NET tracing isn't available in your local machine is because it is not installed. If you look at the [perfview](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/tags/perfview/) help it gives you instructions as to how to enable it.

FYI perfview uses `TracEevent` to capture traces.

Here it is

> ASP.NET Events
>     ASP.NET has a set of events that are sent when each
>   request is process.   PerfView has a special view that you can open
>   when ASP.NET events are turned on.   By default PerfView turns on
>   ASP.NET events, however, you must also have selected the 'Tracing'
>   option when ASP.NET was installed for these events to work.  Thus if
>   you are not seeing ASP.NET events you are running an ASP.NET scenario
>   this is one likely reason why you are not getting data.
>
> To turn on ASP.NET Tracing
>
> The easiest way to turn on tracing is with the DISM tool that comes
>   with the operating system.   Run the following command from an
>   elevated command prompt
>
> `DISM /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:IIS-HttpTracing`
>
> Note that this command will restart the web service (so that it takes effect),
>   which may cause complications if you ASP.NET service handles long
>   (many second) requests. This will either force DISM to delay (for a
>   reboot) or abort the outstanding requests. Thus you may wish to
>   schedule this with other server maintenance. Once this configuration
>   is done on a particular machine, it persists.      You can also do
>   this configuration by hand using a GUI interface.  You first need to
>   get to the dialog for configuring windows software.  This differs
>   depending on whether you are on a Client or Server version of the
>   operating system.
>
> On Client - Start -> Control Panel -> Programs -> Programs and
>   Features ->  Turn Windows features on or off 
>   ->  Internet Information Services -> World Wide Web Services -> Health and Diagnostics -> Tracing  On Server - Start -> Computer -> Right
>   Click -> Manage Roles -> Web Server (IIS) -> Roll Services    Add Role
>   Services Health and Diagnostics -> Tracing

Hope this helps.